# Unable to call function from one file to another

Tags: javascript

In my code, I'm defining function in file_1.js and calling it from file_2.js
and sequence of the file is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="File_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file_2.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me how to call the function from another JS file?

**File_1.js**

```
(function( $ ) {
    function ps_get_posts( divid, type, query_args, cb) {
        var cb = cb || function () {};
        $.ajax({
          url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            action: 'ajax_pagination',
            type: type,
            query_args: query_args
          },
          success: function( html ) {
            cb();
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

          }
        });
    }
})( jQuery );
```

**file_2.js**

```
(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ps_get_posts('#home-section-1 #main', 'card', args);
    });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Indeed, you're defining the function in a function, meaning a private local scope. You'd need to make the function global to be able to call it the way you want to, but whether that's the best thing to do is very debatable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ps_get_posts` is entirely private to the `ready` callback in which you define it. You cannot call it from outside that `ready` callback without exposing it somehow.

You could make it global, but the global namespace on browsers is *incredibly* crowded and in general it's best to avoid globals where you can.

One option is to limit yourself to a **single** global, an object on which you can put the functions you need to access between files. So in `File1.js` you might do:

```
var MyApp = {
    ps_get_posts: function( divid, type, query_args, cb) {
        var cb = cb || function () {};
        $.ajax({
          url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            action: 'ajax_pagination',
            type: type,
            query_args: query_args
          },
          success: function( html ) {
            cb();
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

          }
        });
    }
};
```

...and then in File2.js:

```
MyApp.ps_get_posts(/*...*/);
```

If you have further functions you need to use the same way, you'd add them to your **one** global object, `MyApp`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that the function is in another file, but in another scope. I'll give you an example:

```js
$(function () {
  function myFunction() {
    console.log('Hello world!');
  }
  
  myFunction(); //here the function exists
});


myFunction(); //here the function does not exist
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can create a global object that stores your utility functions to make them reachable, like jQuery does:

```
window.MyUtils= window.MyUtils || {}

window.MYUtils.myFunction= function (...) {...};
```